# How to add a custom delimiter when reading a string word by word

Tags: c++, string, file

I'm reading a file word by word, but sometimes the long dash (or em dash) is in the middle of two words and I wanted to add that as another delimiter (besides the standard whitespace).

```
ifstream file;
file.open("example.txt");
string word;

while (file >> word)
{
    cout << word << endl;
}
```

For example, the phrase "He was young—perhaps from twenty-eight to thirty—tall, slender" prints the words:

```
He
was
young—perhaps
from
twenty-eight
to
thirty—tall
slender
```

"twenty-eight" is fine, but "young" and "perhaps" (and "thirty" and "tall") are two different words and I wanted to read them as such.

How do I add the custom delimiter "—"?

Comment: I would recommend reading the text line by line using `std::readline` and parsing it using proper parsing techniques. `>>` is not one.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. you mean std::getline ? I can't specify more than one delimiter with this function.

Comment: You don't need to. You read *lines of text*. LInes are delimited with the newline character. *Then* you find delimiters in these lines.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. can you answer the question with how exactly this can be done? I can't seem to figure out how this would work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

If you were wanting to treat a single character (like the normal dash '-') as a space I would use `ctype` facet. This type specifies how a local treats characters. In this case we can tell the facet that a '-' is a type of space.

```
#include <locale>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

// This is my facet:
// It adds the '-' character to the set of characters treated like a space.
class DashSepFacet: public std::ctype<char>
{
    public:
        typedef std::ctype<char>   base;
        typedef base::char_type    char_type;

    DashSepFacet(std::locale const& l) : base(table)
    {
        // Get the ctype facet of the current locale
        std::ctype<char> const&  defaultCType = std::use_facet<std::ctype<char> >(l);

        // Copy the default flags for each character from the current facet
        static char data[256];
        for(int loop = 0; loop < 256; ++loop) {data[loop] = loop;}
        defaultCType.is(data, data+256, table);

        // Add the '-' as a space
        table['-'] |= base::space;
    }
    private:
        base::mask table[256];
};

int main()
{
    // Create a stream (Create the locale) then imbue the stream.
    std::fstream data;
    data.imbue(std::locale(data.getloc(), new DashSepFacet(data.getloc())));
    data.open("X3");

    // Now you can use the stream like normal; your locale defines what
    // is whitespace, so the operator `>>` will split on dash.
    std::string   word;
    while(data >> word)
    {
        std::cout << "Word(" << word << ")\n";
    }
}
```

Now we get:

```
> ./a.out
Word(He)
Word(was)
Word(young—perhaps)
Word(from)
Word(twenty)
Word(eight)
Word(to)
Word(thirty—tall)
Word(slender)
```

Unfortunately the `em-dash` is a unicode code point that is actually represented by 3 characters so the above technique does not work. Instead you can use the `char_traits` facet that tells the local to convert character sequences (usually used to convert between formats). In this case we write a version that converts the `em-dash` into a literal space character.

```
#include <locale>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>

class PunctRemove: public std::codecvt<char,char,std::char_traits<char>::state_type>
{
    bool do_always_noconv() const throw()  { return false;}
    int do_encoding()       const throw()  { return true; }

    typedef std::codecvt<char,char,std::char_traits<char>::state_type> MyType;
    typedef MyType::state_type          state_type;
    typedef MyType::result              result;

    virtual result  do_in(state_type& s,
            const char* from,const char* from_end,const char*& from_next,
            char* to,        char* to_limit,      char*& to_next  ) const
    {
        // Unicode for em-dash is
        // e2  80  94
        static int emdashpos = 0;

        /*
         * This function is used to filter the input
         */
        for(from_next = from, to_next = to;from_next != from_end;++from_next)
        {
            // Note we do it this way.
            // because the multi byte em-dash may be split across buffer boundaries.
            if (emdashpos == 0 && *from_next == '\xe2') {
                ++emdashpos;
                continue;
            }
            else if (emdashpos == 1 && *from_next == '\x80') {
                ++emdashpos;
                continue;
            }
            else if (emdashpos == 2 && *from_next == '\x94') {
                *to_next = ' ';
                ++to_next;
                emdashpos=0;
                continue;
            }
            // --- Account for times when we received some characters but not all
            if (emdashpos != 0) {
                from_next -= emdashpos;
                emdashpos = 0;
            }

            // Normal processing.
            *to_next = *from_next;
            ++to_next;
        }
        return ok;
    }

    /*
     * This function is used to filter the output
     */
    virtual result do_out(state_type& state,
            const char* from, const char* from_end, const char*& from_next,
            char* to,         char* to_limit,       char*& to_next  ) const
    { /* Write if you need it */ return ok;}
};


int main()
{
    // Create a stream (Create the locale) then imbue the stream.
    std::ifstream data;
    data.imbue(std::locale(data.getloc(), new PunctRemove()));
    data.open("X3");

    // Now you can use the stream like normal; your locale is replacing the em-dash
    // with a normal space.
    std::string   word;
    while(data >> word)
    {
        std::cout << "Word(" << word << ")\n";
    }
}
```

Now we get:

```
> ./a.out
Word(He)
Word(was)
Word(young)
Word(perhaps)
Word(from)
Word(twenty-eight)
Word(to)
Word(thirty)
Word(tall)
Word(slender)
```

Comment: Magic numbers like `\xe2` are not a good idea, and what about other punctuation? The code will get very unwieldy very quickly.